# checkbox should send false if checkbox is not selected when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#chek').click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                    $("#btnSubmit").html("true");
                }
                else {
                    $("#btnSubmit").html("false");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <form method="post">

       <input type="checkbox" id = "chek" name="readAlread" value="true"> true
        <input type="checkbox" name="readAlread" value="false"> false
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id ="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="chek">Добавить
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, I'm a newbie, looked everywhere on the Internet but couldn't find the answer to my question.. If the checkbox is not selected, I need to send false to the server. on the server I have a type of variable stored boolean Working in IDEA, using java, spring, hibernate. In the controller class I have a request

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestParam Boolean readAlready, Map<String, Object> model) {
     ......
        return "main";
    }
```

Если я не выбираю галочку в checkboxe то у меня вылетает ошибка на сайте

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat May 26 20:09:56 MSK 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required Boolean parameter 'readAlready' is not present
```

Comment: "Если я не выбираю галочку в checkboxe то у меня вылетает ошибка на сайте" - Please translate that. That would make it easier to answer your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really sound like a situation where you would want a radio control instead of checkboxes. Radios allow you to have multiple options for one input name that will automatically swap if you click the opposite option. This would eliminate the need for your javascript also.

```
<input type="radio" name="readAlread" value="true"> true
<input type="radio" name="readAlread" value="false"> false
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have one checkbox (not two), and read the value (checked = true, not checked = false) on the server? Having two checkboxes makes a strange user experience, and your solution is unnecessarily complicated.

The state (checked/unchecked) of the checkbox is submit to the server, as part of the form. Just read it there.